# How do I sort the List by a property of the Objects in the collection?

Tags: java, hibernate, list, sorting

So I've resigned myself to not being able to use the order of a List reliably because hibernate reverses it and everyone says don't do it, so I've added a field to my class as position.  I have:

```
@Entity
class Procedure {
...
int procedureId;
List<Task> tasks;
...
}

@Entity
class Task {
...
int taskId;
int position;
}
```

Now I don't know how to approach interacting with the list.  Should I just sort it by position when I first get it from the db and start working with it, and then I can leave all the user-rearranging code that I've already written and then just reset all the positions on save to the order the list so I can resort when I get back?

SKIP TO ACTUAL QUESTION HERE:

This seems to be the best approach, but HOW do I sort the List by a property of the Objects in the collection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To sort by position, for example, you can use

```
java.util.Collections.sort(tasks, new Comparator<Task>() {
@Override
public int compare(Task t1, Task t2) {
    return t1.getPosition() - t2.getPosition();
});
```

Yuval =8-)

Answer (score 3):

If you want the list order to be preserved by Hibernate, you should probably use `<list-index>` to map the index column, as described in [6.2.3 Indexed Collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/collections-mapping.html#collections-indexed), instead of adding it as field of Task and sorting it yourself.

This way, your Java code doesn't have to worry about the index values at all. The list will be properly sorted when returned by Hibernate, and Hibernate will take care of updating the indexes when the list is modified.

Comment: Ah, finally there it is, the correct solution, though when I try to implement it, the database I already have balks, so I might not implement the real solution this project, though next for certain. :)

Thank you!